# How to send a very large array to the client browser?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I have a very large array (20 million numbers, output of a sql query) in my MVC application and I need to send it to the client browser (it will be visualized on a map using webGL and the user is supposed to play with the data locally). What is the best approach to send the data? (Please just do not suggest this is a bad idea! I am looking for an answer to this specific question, not alternative suggestions)
This is my current code (called using ajax), but when array size goes above 3 millions I receive outofmemory exception. It seems the serialization (stringbuilder?) fails.

```
List<double> results = DomainModel.GetPoints();
JsonResult result = Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
result.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
return result;
```

I do not have much experience with web programming/javascript/MVC. I have been researching for the past 24 hours but did not get anywhere, so I need a hint/sample code to continue my research.

Answer (score 2):

**NO, NO, NO**, you do not send that much information to the browser:

1. it results in a huge memory usage that will most likely crash the web-browser (and in fact in your case it does)
2. it takes a large amount of time to retrieve it, not everyone has a good internet connection, and even good connections can fluctuate over time

If you're building a map tool, then I'd recommend splitting the map into tiles and sending only the data corresponding to the portion of the map the user is currently working on. Also for larger zooms you can filter out data, as surely you can't place it all on the map.

**Edit.** A somewhat another alternative would be to ask your users to use machines with at least 16GB of RAM, or whatever RAM size is needed to deal with your huge data).

Comment: I totally understand your concerns, but users of this application have very good and reliable  internet access, and I prefer not to use tiling, unless I do observe browser crash. Any suggestion regarding my actual question?

Comment: Please see point #1 from my answer, you do observe crashes, and you cannot avoid the crashes unless you send only a piece of the huge data. Or, instruct your users to use machines with >16GB of ram (or whatever RAM size can deal with your huge amount of data) :)

Comment: most likely is different than observation! I ask my users to get 256GB of RAM, if that will get us start talking about an answer to my question.

Comment: Updated my answer to include this RAM "approach" :)

Comment: @MattMan, I think the point cristik is trying to make is that a web browser is not an appropriate platform for this application in the first place. Demanding users have more RAM than most **servers** possess is an extreme system requirement. Also, it requires that users have 64-bit web browsers (still not ubiquitous) that are optimized for such demands (and I'm not aware of any).

Comment: @alroc, I have already sent more than 3 millions numbers without any issue. The browser memory usage is around 450 MB, but the serialization fails after that. Help me to figure out what is the maximum array size the browser can handle. Once I figure that out, I can decide how to proceed. I have already developed an Opengl program to visualize the points, but I would like to investigate the potentials of browsers for my application.